# How do I convert SQL Time records to seconds?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I am wanting to calculate the numbers of seconds for records stored in SQL Time format (e.g. 11:33:00) into the number of seconds from the start of the day (in this instance 41580, i.e. (11*60*60)+(33*60)) using PHP, so that I can add these seconds to a variable to calculate a DateTime.  It appears that I can't use strtotime to do this.  Do I need to write a function, and if so, could someone suggest an efficient function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the MySQL function [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec), I think. It does exactly what you want. You would use it inside the `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(your_time_column) AS seconds FROM ...
```

Comment: @Nick Oh yes.. What was I thinking? Fixed.